# Simplify my Linked list "search and delete" function

Tags: c, linked-list

The function asks the user for a value to search for, then deletes all matching values in the list.

The program runs flawlessly, but I can't figure out a simple/elegant way of separating cases for 'first node', 'last node', and 'intermediate node'.

Please help me make it more elegant and readable.

I'll post the relevant code block, followed by the whole program.

In the relevant function, the following code block is part of the switch-case construct I'm using(If user inputs 'v', it means search for a 'value' and delete, as opposed to 'delete the first node' or 'delete the last node')

```
case 'v':
            printf("\n\tEnter value to delete:\t");
            scanf("%d",&value);
            r=q;
            if(!q)//If linked list is empty
            {
                printf("\n\t\tLinked list is EMPTY\n");
                return;
            }
            else if(!(q->next))//If linked list consists of only one node
            {
                if((q->data)==value)
                {
                    free(q);
                    printf("\nValue found and deleted in position 1\n");
                    count=1;
                }
            }
            else//If linked list consists of more than one node
            {
                for(i=1;q;i++)
                {
                    if(q->data==value)
                    {
                        if(i==1)//for first node
                        {
                            q=q->next;
                            free(r);
                            *pp=q;
                            printf("\nValue found and deleted in position 1\n");
                            count=1;
                        }
                        else//for the rest of the nodes
                        {
                            printf("\nValue found and deleted in position %d\n",i);
                            r->next=q->next;
                            temp=q;
                            q=q->next;
                            free(temp);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        r=q;
                        q=q->next;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(count==0)//If no matches are found
                printf("Value not found");
            break;
```

Complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int count(struct node *);
void traverse(struct node *);
void insert(struct node **);
void delete(struct node **);
void deletelist(struct node **);

int main()
{   char choice;
    struct node *head, **tohead;
    head=(struct node *)malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    head=NULL;
    tohead=&head;
    do
    {
        printf("\nChoose operation to perform:\n");
        printf("\tCount number of nodes(c):\n");
        printf("\tInsert a node(i)\n");
        printf("\tDelete a node(d)\n");
        printf("\tDelete the list(D)\n");
        printf("\tShow currenct linked list(s)\n");
        printf("\tQuit without saving changes(q):\t");
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'i':
                insert(tohead);
                break;
            case 'c':
                printf("\nList count is %d\n",count(head));
                break;
            case 's':
                traverse(head);
                break;
            case 'q':
                printf("QUITTING\n");
                break;
            case 'd':
                delete(tohead);
                break;
            case 'D':
                deletelist(tohead);
                break;
            default:
                printf("\n\tINVALID CHOICE\n");
        }
    }while(choice!='q');
}

int count(struct node *p)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;p;i++)
        p=p->next;
    return i;
}

void traverse(struct node *p)
{
    printf("\nLinked list looks like: ");

    if(!p)
    {
        printf("nothing. It's EMPTY");
    }
    else
    {   while(p)
        {
            printf("%d\t",p->data);
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void insert(struct node **pp)
{
    int value,position;
    struct node *q;
    q=*pp;
    struct node *newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Insert what number?:\t");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    printf("In what position? Push '0' for last,'1' for first");
    printf("\n\t\tOR\nenter position no.:\t");
    scanf("%d",&position);
    newnode->data=value;
    if(position==1)
    {   newnode->next=q;
        *pp=newnode;
    }
    else if(position==0)
    {
        if(!q)
        {
            newnode->next=q;
            *pp=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            while(q->next)
                q=q->next;
            q->next=newnode;
            newnode->next=NULL;
        }
    }
    else if((position>1)&&(position<=count(q)+1))
    {
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<position-1;i++)
            q=q->next;
        newnode->next=q->next;
        q->next=newnode;
    }
    else
        printf("\n\t\tINVALID POSITION\n");
}

void delete(struct node **pp)
{
    struct node *q,*r,*temp;
    q=*pp;
    int i,count=0,value,position;
    char choice;
    printf("\n\tPush 'v' to delete a specific value");
    printf("\n\t\t\tOR");
    printf("\n\t'1' to delete the first value");
    printf("\n\t'0' to delete the last value:\t");
    scanf(" %c",&choice);
    if(q==NULL)
    {   printf("List is EMPTY\n");
        return;
    }
    switch(choice)
    {
        case '1':
            *pp=q->next;
            free(q);
            break;
        case '0':
            while(q->next!=NULL)
            {
                r=q;
                q=q->next;
            }
            r->next=NULL;
            free(q);
            break;
        case 'v':
            printf("\n\tEnter value to delete:\t");
            scanf("%d",&value);
            r=q;
            if(!q)//If linked list is empty
            {
                printf("\n\t\tLinked list is EMPTY\n");
                return;
            }
            else if(!(q->next))//If linked list consists of only one node
            {
                if((q->data)==value)
                {
                    free(q);
                    printf("\nValue found and deleted in position 1\n");
                    count=1;
                }
            }
            else//If linked list consists of more than one node
            {
                for(i=1;q;i++)
                {
                    if(q->data==value)
                    {
                        if(i==1)//for first node
                        {
                            q=q->next;
                            free(r);
                            *pp=q;
                            printf("\nValue found and deleted in position 1\n");
                            count=1;
                        }
                        else//for the rest of the nodes
                        {
                            printf("\nValue found and deleted in position %d\n",i);
                            r->next=q->next;
                            temp=q;
                            q=q->next;
                            free(temp);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        r=q;
                        q=q->next;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(count==0)//If no matches are found
                printf("Value not found");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nBad choice");
    }return;
}

void deletelist(struct node **pp)
{
    struct node *p,*temp;
    p=*pp;
    while(p)
    {
        temp=p;
        p=p->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    *pp=NULL;
    printf("\nLIST DELETED\n");
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @YuHao How do flag this for Code Review?

Comment: @drum Vote to close supports custom reason of off-topic, [you need 3K reputation to access it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: `head=(struct node *)malloc (sizeof(struct node));head=NULL;` : memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

```
void filter(struct node **pp, int value){
    struct node *curr, *prev=NULL, *tmp;
    curr = *pp;
    if(!curr)
        return ;
    tmp = curr;
    while(tmp){
        if(tmp->data != value){
            curr->data = tmp->data;
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    deletelist(&curr);
    if(prev){
        prev->next = NULL;
    } else {
        *pp = NULL;
    }
}
```